# Spring Rest Data - Foreign Key object URL not converted in @RequestBody

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data

I'm using Spring Rest Data and I have configured my application to use RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration. I have the following 2 entities:

Enterprise have many User relationship.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="enterprise")
public class Enterprise extends BaseEntity
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="enterprise_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="enterprise_name")
    private String name;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User extends BaseEntity
{
    @Id
    @Column(name="user_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "owner_enterprise_id", referencedColumnName = "enterprise_id")
    private Enterprise ownerEnterprise;

    @Column(name="username")
    private String userName;

    @Column(name="emailaddress")
    private String emailAddress;

    @Column(name="passwordhash")
    private String password;
}
```

I was able to send post request to create enterprise, and the next thing i want to do is create a User that has a FK to the enterprise.

Here is my UserController:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/createUser", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<User> register(@RequestBody User user) {

    User newUser = userService.register(user);
    return new ResponseEntity<User>(newUser, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

When I try to send post to create new user:

```
curl -i -X POST \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"userName":"johndoe", "emailAddress":"johndoe@gmail.com", "password":"johnpass1", "ownerEnterprise":"http://localhost:8080/enterprises/1"
}' \
http://localhost:8080/createUser
```

I put breakpoints in my controller and saw that the User object's ownerEnterprise field was null (but other fields contain correct data). 
Could someone please help show me what I am missing? I have tried to search this for hours and no luck.

I've also verified that the url is correct:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/enterprises/1 

    {
      "name" : "MyEnterprise",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/enterprises/1"
        }
      }
    }
```

Thanks a bunch for your time!!

Answer (score 2):

Your interface is not a Spring-Data-REST based one, it is a straight Spring MVC request, so the following kind of a POST should work for you:

```
{"userName":"johndoe", "emailAddress":"johndoe@gmail.com", "password":"johnpass1", "ownerEnterprise":{"id":1, "name":"Test Enterprise"}}
```

Essentially this is a json representation of your `User` entity.

Had you exposed your User entity as a `@RepositoryRestResource` then your original request should work

Comment: But according to this guide: http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/.. 
 @RepositoryRestResource is not required for a repository to be exported. It is only used to change the export details, such as using /people instead of the default value of /persons.

Comment: I tried adding @RepositoryRestResource to my UserRepository class and still the same issue.. :x

Comment: did you also remove this specific controller - @RepositoryRestResource exposes its own set of endpoints

Comment: Yah i tried send the post request to /users too but i got the same error

Comment: Still stuck on this... help would be very much appreciated. :(

Comment: If you can share your project somewhere I can try and help.

Comment: did you find a solution for this problem? I  have the same problem here

Comment: You are suggesting switching from RestController to RepositoryRestResource!!! Omg it's like my car tire is broken, okay that will be fixed when you buy a new car but another brand?? You could've also suggested a new language or a framework. I need RestController and somehow to "auto" bind those foreign keys from URLs and not Posting that big object as a whole everytime I want to reference it.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem. Adding a constructor in your enterprise class should solve it.

```
public Enterprise(Long id) {
    super();
    this.id = id;

}
```